# メインのPythonを2つのスレッドに分け、このスレッド間でやりとりをしたい。

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi

一つのCPUで、２つの動作を行いながら、それらの間でやりとりをしたいと考えています。
というのも、Raspberry PiとiOSアプリ間でBluetooth通信を行いながら、必要に応じてRaspi上でPythonスクリプトを実行したいからです。

## 実際にそのようなことは可能でしょうか？

今考えている構成は次のようなものです。

---

Pythonを実行している時に、threadingモジュールで２スレッドに分けます。

1. 一つ目のスレッドでは、[subprocessモジュールによってjavascriptファイルを実行します](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788729/start-node-app-from-python-script)。

   この実行中のjavascript(node.js)では、[blenoというモジュールを用いて、bluetooth peripheralとして動作させます](https://qiita.com/uzuki_aoba/items/346e28b6e9170ce85a6c)。
2. 二つ目のスレッドでは、通常のPythonスクリプトが実行されています。例えば、Raspiの純正カメラの制御などを行います。　さらに、こちらはサーバーとして動作させます。一つ目のスレッドの[javascriptの要求に応じて](https://kivantium.net/python-ajax)、写真を取得したり、測定時間を返したりします。これはjQueryやAjaxを使うのが有効であるようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

上述のような構成で可能なのかどうか、他にうまいやり方があるかどうか、と言った内容についてご回答いただければ幸いです。

---

### 追記：

blenoをわざわざ使う理由（bluezやpybluezなどではなく）は、blenoのインターフェイスが非常に分かりやす‌​いからです。サービスやキャラクタリスティ‌​ックとしての実装が簡単です。

Comment: 一読した感じだと、どうして2つのプログラムをわざわざ Python の threading を使って分ける必要があるのか分かりませんでした。この Python プログラムは RasPi 上で動作しているのですよね。片方の Python プログラムで結局外部の Node.js を実行することしかしないのであれば、単に Node.js と サーバープログラムをプロセスレベルで並行に走らせれば良いのではないでしょうか。スレッド間で何かしらデータを共有したいというのであればスレッド単位で分けたくなるかと思いますが、現状ネットワーク越しでやり取りする設計になさっているのですよね。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん

知識不足でして、プログラムを並行して走らせる方法としてたまたまthreadingを見つけた、という形です。他に方法があるなら、それで一向に構いません。プロセスレベルでというのは、どういうことになるでしょうか？

コメントを本文に追記致しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 一つのCPUで、２つの動作を行いながら、それらの間でやりとりをしたいと考えています。
>   実際にそのようなことは可能でしょうか？

可能です。

モダンなオペレーティング・システムは何らかのマルチタスキング機構を備えているため、単一CPUであっても複数タスクを並行に処理することが出来ます。

- マルチプロセス：OS上で複数のプロセス(process)を同時稼動させる方式。プロセス間の結合度は低く、データ共有にはプロセス間通信(IPC; Inter Process Communication)機構が必要。
- マルチスレッド：単一プロセス内に、複数のスレッド(thread)を同時稼動させる方式。スレッド間の結合度は高く、同一メモリ空間を共有するため特別な通信機構は不用。

---

> 一つ目のスレッドでは、subprocessモジュールによってjavascriptファイルを実行します。
>   二つ目のスレッドでは、通常のPythonスクリプトが実行されています。

ただし、その実現手段としてPythonのthreadingモジュール（マルチスレッド）が好ましいかといえば、質問中にある要件に対しては「適切でない」と考えます。

- **前提：**「マルチスレッド」よりも「マルチプロセス」の方がプログラミングモデルが単純であり、並行処理プログラム特有の難解さ・困難さが抑えられます。
- 本質的にはJavaScriptスクリプトとPythonスクリプト間の連携ですから、それぞれのインタプリタ(Node.js, CPython)プロセスを立ち上げる単純な「マルチプロセス」並行処理で十分です。
- スクリプト間でのローカル通信による"疎な"連携を想定しているようようですから、分離独立性の高い「マルチプロセス」並行処理で十分です。